# Fitting tooltip completely inside a feature else removing it in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have been using tooltips as a form of labeling my polygons in Leaflet. The problem I'm not able to solve is to remove the labels from the view that doesn't fit completely inside the feature. Something similar to what happens when we select **Only draw labels which fit completely in the feature** in QGIS

The polygons are in GeoJSON format and I'm using the latest Leaflet version.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Look at https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering and https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel for some possible workarounds.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks for the reply. I did try my hands at the plugins available but to my luck couldn't find a solution. If you have by any chance worked on similar problem earlier and can share some reference code please do help :)

Comment: I did work on a similar problem, and that's why [`L.LayerGroup.Collision`](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision) exists.

Comment: Have a similar need. My initial thoughts was to get the longest horizontal or vertical line (of width = font size) that fits in the polygon and display the label in the center of this line. (Label can be vertical in my case).